# Using processEvents() in a while loop inside in a Function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a slot function

```
    void MobilePlatform::slot_lineFollow(bool checked) 
    {
        while(checked){
            ...
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(); 
        }
        if(!checked){
            ....
        }
    }
```

This function is a function that is requested from a **QCheckBox** and when the **checkbox** is pressed the variable `checked` are true and go into the while loop, and when the **checkbox** is not pressed the variable `checked` are `false` and go out from the while loop and goes into the if block, this is normal, but what I don't understand is, why in the next step goes to `QcoreApplication::processEvents()` and when it goes out, the variable `checked` are true.

Knows anybody why these happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a part of your code that changes the value of `checked`? Currently nothing indicates so, so your `while` loop should run forever.

Comment: You should also explain what are you trying to achieve with this `while` loop.

Comment: I agree with @thuga that context would be useful. In addtion, any while loop that prevents event processing and requires that call to 'processEvents' is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: It's really easy: **forget this approach**. It'll solve all your problems. Reentering the event loop is never a solution.

Comment: @KubaOber It is frightening how often a question/answer which involves `processEvents` pops up on this site. There should be a note in the docs which states that this method should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You've got bitten by the fallout from reentering the event loop. Now you know why it's not a good idea. Never block in the main thread, and never reenter the event loop. Invert the flow of control to accurately reflect the asynchronous reality:

```
class MobilePlatform : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  using self = MobilePlatform;
  using base_class = QWidget;
  using spin_handler = void (self::*)();
  QBasicTimer m_spinTimer;
  ...

  Q_SIGNAL void spinSignal();
  void spin(spin_handler);
  void despin(spin_handler);
  void follower();
  Q_SLOT void slot_lineFollow(bool checked);
protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) override;
public:
  ...
};

void MobilePlatform::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *ev) {
  if (ev->timerId() == m_spinTimer.timerId())
    Q_EMIT spinSignal();
  else
    base_class::timerEvent(ev);
}

void MobilePlatform::spin(spin_handler handler) {
  if (!m_spinTimer.isActive())
    m_spinTimer.start(0, this);
  connect(this, &self::spinSignal, this, handler, Qt::UniqueConnection | Qt::DirectConnection);
  Q_ASSERT(m_spinTimer.isActive());
}

void MobilePlatform::despin(spin_handler handler) {
  static const auto signal = QMetaMethod::fromSignal(&self::spinSignal);
  Q_ASSERT(signal.isValid());
  disconnect(this, &self::spinSignal, this, handler);
  auto const hasHandlers = isSignalConnected(signal);
  if (!hasHandlers)
    m_spinTimer.stop();
  Q_ASSERT(m_spinTimer.isActive() == hasHandlers);
}

void MobilePlatform::follower() {
  /* code that runs when following */
  ...
}

void MobilePlatform::slot_lineFollow(bool checked) {
  if (checked()) {
    spin(&self::follower);
  } else {
    despin(&self::follower);
    ...
  }
}
```